# When using export-csv my special character is showing as an ?. Is it possible to bulk remove the special character?

Tags: powershell, special-characters, export-csv

when running the below code:

```
$folderPath = '\\dc1\shared\BI\HisRms\'

$folderPathDest = 'C:\Users\jonathon.kindred\Desktop\RM2\'


$Columns = 'SKU', 'Landed Cost',  'Current Std Price',  'Current Sale Price',  'Free Stock',  'Markdown',  'Published Calc'


Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name |


ForEach-Object { 


    $filePath = $folderPath + $_


    $filePathdest = $folderPathDest + $_


    Import-Csv $filePath | Select $Columns |
    Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest
}
```

the 'Landed Cost',  'Current Std Price',  'Current Sale Price' ends up beginning with ? e.g. ?12.00.

I would just like to remove the £ sign from these columns during the export so i just have the decimal value. Does anyone know how i would do this?

Comment: `... |Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest -Encoding unicode`

Answer (score 1):

You can bulk remove special character £  like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv $filePath | Select $Columns
$csv | Export-csv $FilePathDesc -Encoding Unicode
```

The special character is a pound sign  And encoding is Unicode.

Comment: this doesn't work sorry, it does the below to my data:
```
SKU,"Landed Cost","Current Std Price","Current Sale Price","Free Stock","Markdown","Published Calc"
S18W-1000023452-LRD,"�6.50","�20.00","�20.00","86","No","Published"
S17W-1300003383-WTE,"�9.50","�25.00","�25.00","136","No","Published"
S18W-2800023541-WTE,"�7.25","�18.00","�18.00","61","No","Published"
S18W-2800023540-BCK,"�5.25","�18.00","�18.00","68","No","Published"

Comment: The default encoding of export-csv is ascii in ps 5.

Answer (score 0):

Also:  when you see a `?` in output, it means that the current character-set which is being used *to display it on your terminal* does not recognize that it's Unicode.  Or maybe it does, but it doesn't have a code-point for that particular character.